# MoviePY lum_contrast

Tags: python, moviepy

Maybe someone know how to use `moviepy.video.fx.all.lum_contrast`?

I try to use it like stabdart crop and resize:

```
clip = VideoFileClip("clip.mp4")
clip2 = clip.lum_contrast(1, 1, 126)
clip2.write_videofile("clip_changed.mp4")
```

But I get some errors:

```
    clip2 = clip.lum_contrast( 1, 1, 126)
AttributeError: 'VideoFileClip' object has no attribute 'lum_contrast'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/videofx.html) something like this should work:

```py
import moviepy.video.fx.all as vfx

clip = VideoFileClip("clip.mp4")
clip2 = clip.fx(vfx.lum_contrast, lum=1, contrast=1, contrast_thr=126)
clip2.write_videofile("clip_changed.mp4")
```